# Javascript Uncaught TypeError: is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have an assignment to write a script that takes a users birth month, day, and year. It then calculates the number of years, months, days, hours, and minutes the person has lived. Also it is suppose to count the number of days till the persons next birthday. I have written a function called leapYear() that does a couple of equations to check if the year is a leap year and it works fine, but if I try to call the function more than once inside of another function I get 'Uncaught TypeError: leapYear is not a function'. Can someone please advise on where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML 5 Template</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <!-- USE ONLY IF using author's modernizr JavaScript file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- USE ONLY IF using external JavaScript file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--  USE ONLY IF using document level JavaScript -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="form">
        <h1>Age Calculator</h1>
        <h2>Enter Your Birthdate:</h2>
        <form method="get" onsubmit="return false">
            <p>
                <label for="day">Day:</label><br>
                <select name="day" id="day">
                    <script> dayList(); </script>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for = "month">Month:</label><br>
                    <select name="month" id="month">
                        <option value="1">January</option>
                        <option value="2">February</option>
                        <option value="3">March</option>
                        <option value="4">April</option>
                        <option value="5">May</option>
                        <option value="6">June</option>
                        <option value="7">July</option>
                        <option value="8">August</option>
                        <option value="9">September</option>
                        <option value="10">October</option>
                        <option value="11">November</option>
                        <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="year">Year:</label><br>
                    <select name="year" id="year">
                        <script> yearList();</script>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p class="left">
                    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="ageCalc()">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                </p>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="results">
        <p>
            You've been living for: <br>
            <p id="yearsLived"></p> Years, <br>
            <p id="monthsLived"></p> Months, <br>
            <p id="daysLived"></p> Days, <br>
            <p id="hoursLived"></p> Hours, and <br>
            <p id="minLived"></p> Minutes. <br>
            <p id="daysTillBD"></p> Days till your birthday.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.js

```
    //Global Variables
var date = new Date();
var currentMin = date.getMinutes();
var currentHour = date.getHours();
var currentDay = date.getDate();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
var month = {
  1: 31,
  2: 28,
  3: 31,
  4: 30,
  5: 31,
  6: 30,
  7: 31,
  8: 31,
  9: 30,
  10: 31,
  11: 30,
  12: 31
};



//Fill Day Form Data
function dayList() {
  var counter = 1;
  while (counter <= 31) {
    document.write("<option value='" + counter + "'>" + counter + "</option>");
    var counter = counter + 1;
  }
};



//Fill Year Form Data
function yearList() {
  var counter = date.getFullYear();

  while (counter >= 1950) {
    document.write("<option value='" + counter + "'>" + counter + "</option>");
    var counter = counter - 1;
  }
};



//Check if birth year is leap year
function leapYear(birthYear) {
  var num = (birthYear / 4) % 1;
  var num2 = (birthYear / 100) % 1;
  var num3 = (birthYear / 400) % 1;

  if (num == 0 || (num2 == 0 && num3 == 0)) {
    daysInYear = 366;
    month[2] = 29;
    leapYear = true;
  }
  else {
    daysInYear = 365;
    month[2] = 28;
    leapYear = false;
  }
};



//Age Calculator
function ageCalc() {
  var birthDay = parseInt(document.getElementById('day').value);
  var birthMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);
  var birthYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('year').value);
  var yearsLived = currentYear - birthYear;
  var monthsLived = 0;
  var daysLived = 0;
  var hoursLived = currentHour;
  var minLived = currentMin;
  var daysTillBD = 0;
  var count = 0;

  //Days Untill birthday
  leapYear(currentYear);
  if (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
    daysTillBD = month[currentMonth] - currentDay;
    var testMonth = currentMonth;
    while (testMonth != 12) {
      testMonth++;
      daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
    }
    var testYear = currentYear + 1;
    leapYear(testYear);
    testMonth = 1;
    while (testMonth != birthMonth) {
      daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
      testMonth++;
    }
    daysTillBD = daysTillBD + (birthDay - 1);
  }
  else if (birthMonth > currentMonth) {
    daysTillBD = month[currentMonth] - currentDay;
    var testMonth = currentMonth + 1;
    while (testMonth != birthMonth) {
      daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
      testMonth++;
    }
    daysTillBD = daysTillBD + (birthDay - 1);
  }
  else {
    if (birthDay < currentDay) {
      daysTillBD = month[currentMonth] - currentDay;
      var testMonth = currentMonth + 1;
      while (testMonth != birthMonth && testMonth <= 12) {
        daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
        testMonth++;
      }
      var testMonth = 1;
      while (testMonth != birthMonth) {
        daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
        testMonth++;
      }
      daysTillBD = daysTillBD + (birthDay - 1);
    }
    else if (birthDay > currentDay) {
      daysTillBD = birthDay - currentDay;
    }
  }




  //Results Display
  document.getElementById('yearsLived').innerHTML = yearsLived;
  document.getElementById('monthsLived').innerHTML = monthsLived;
  document.getElementById('daysLived').innerHTML = daysLived;
  document.getElementById('hoursLived').innerHTML = hoursLived;
  document.getElementById('minLived').innerHTML = minLived;
  document.getElementById('daysTillBD').innerHTML = daysTillBD;

};
```

style.css

```
h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size 50px;
  text-indent: 150px;
}

form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#form {
  width: 50%;
  height: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px black double;
}

#form.p {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

#form.p.left {
  float: right;
}

#results {

}

#results.p {

}
```

Comment: Please give more details. On which line does the error occur? Upon which function call?

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that you do wrong.

First, remember that in JavaScript if you do assignment like this:

```
leapYear = true;
```

You write into a **global** variable called `leapYear`, not into a variable bound to a scope of the current function. To write into a local variable, you should write

```
var leapYear = true;
```

All assignments and references into `leapYear` after such line within the same funciton will write into a local variable, not into a global one.

Second, remember that functions in javascript can be stored into a variable similarly to an integer or a string. So, when you write `function leapYear`, you declare a variable `leapYear` that stores a function. When you write `leapYear = true` you overwrite that variable and not it stores a boolean. If you then try to call `leapYear()` you will get the error, because now `leapYear` stores a boolean, not a function, and boolean is not callable.

So to fix your problem, you can just prepend `leapYear = false` with `var`. In your particular case, however, you can just remove `leapYear = false` and `leapYear = true` lines altogether, because you do not ever use those value afterwards. One last note: if your intent was to *return* that value, you should write `return false;` instead of `leapYear = false;` (which would be a correct way to return a value in Delphi, for example).

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized that function names and variables where so close. I feel really stupid because I had put the leapYear = true/false variable at the beginning of the project then decided against it but neglected to remove it from the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your have problem why your code contains de variable e funcion with same name (leapYear). Change name of variable ou function and after run new test.

Look this example:

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-size 10px;
  text-indent: 150px;
}
form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
#form {
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px black double;
}
#form.p {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: 0, auto;
}
#form.p.left {
  float: right;
}

#results {}
```

```html
<script>
    //Global Variables
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMin = date.getMinutes();
    var currentHour = date.getHours();
    var currentDay = date.getDate();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
    var month = {
        1: 31,
        2: 28,
        3: 31,
        4: 30,
        5: 31,
        6: 30,
        7: 31,
        8: 31,
        9: 30,
        10: 31,
        11: 30,
        12: 31
    };

    //Fill Day Form Data
    function dayList() {
        var counter = 1;
        while (counter <= 31) {
            document.write("<option value='" + counter + "'>" + counter + "</option>");
            var counter = counter + 1;
        }
    };

    //Fill Year Form Data
    function yearList() {
        var counter = date.getFullYear();
        
        while (counter >= 1950) {
            document.write("<option value='" + counter + "'>" + counter + "</option>");
            var counter = counter - 1;
        }
    };

    //Check if birth year is leap year
    function leapYearCalc(birthYear) {
        var num = (birthYear / 4) % 1;
        var num2 = (birthYear / 100) % 1;
        var num3 = (birthYear / 400) % 1;
        
        if (num == 0 || (num2 == 0 && num3 == 0)) {
            daysInYear = 366;
            month[2] = 29;
            leapYear = true;
        } else {
            daysInYear = 365;
            month[2] = 28;
            leapYear = false;
        }
    };

    //Age Calculator
    function ageCalc() {
        var birthDay = parseInt(document.getElementById('day').value);
        var birthMonth = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);
        var birthYear = parseInt(document.getElementById('year').value);
        var yearsLived = currentYear - birthYear;
        var monthsLived = 0;
        var daysLived = 0;
        var hoursLived = currentHour;
        var minLived = currentMin;
        var daysTillBD = 0;
        var count = 0;
        
        //Days Untill birthday
        leapYearCalc(currentYear);
        if (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
            daysTillBD = month[currentMonth] - currentDay;
            var testMonth = currentMonth;
            while (testMonth != 12) {
                testMonth++;
                daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
            }
            var testYear = currentYear + 1;
            leapYearCalc(testYear);
            testMonth = 1;
            while (testMonth != birthMonth) {
                daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
                testMonth++;
            }
            daysTillBD = daysTillBD + (birthDay - 1);
        } else if (birthMonth > currentMonth) {
            daysTillBD = month[currentMonth] - currentDay;
            var testMonth = currentMonth + 1;
            while (testMonth != birthMonth) {
                daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
                testMonth++;
            }
            daysTillBD = daysTillBD + (birthDay - 1);
        } else {
            if (birthDay < currentDay) {
                daysTillBD = month[currentMonth] - currentDay;
                var testMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                while (testMonth != birthMonth && testMonth <= 12) {
                    daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
                    testMonth++;
                }
                var testMonth = 1;
                while (testMonth != birthMonth) {
                    daysTillBD = daysTillBD + month[testMonth];
                    testMonth++;
                }
                daysTillBD = daysTillBD + (birthDay - 1);
            } else if (birthDay > currentDay) {
                daysTillBD = birthDay - currentDay;
            }
        }
        
        //Results Display
        document.getElementById('yearsLived').innerHTML = yearsLived;
        document.getElementById('monthsLived').innerHTML = monthsLived;
        document.getElementById('daysLived').innerHTML = daysLived;
        document.getElementById('hoursLived').innerHTML = hoursLived;
        document.getElementById('minLived').innerHTML = minLived;
        document.getElementById('daysTillBD').innerHTML = daysTillBD;
    }; 
</script>
<div id="form">
    <h1>Age Calculator</h1>
    
    <form method="get" onsubmit="return false">
        <p>
            <label for="day">Day:</label>
            <br>
            <select name="day" id="day">
                <script>
                dayList();
                </script>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="month">Month:</label>
            <br>
            <select name="month" id="month">
                <option value="1">January</option>
                <option value="2">February</option>
                <option value="3">March</option>
                <option value="4">April</option>
                <option value="5">May</option>
                <option value="6">June</option>
                <option value="7">July</option>
                <option value="8">August</option>
                <option value="9">September</option>
                <option value="10">October</option>
                <option value="11">November</option>
                <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="year">Year:</label>
            <br>
            <select name="year" id="year">
                <script>
                yearList();
                </script>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p class="left">
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="ageCalc()">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="results">
    <p>
        You've been living for:
        <br>
        <p id="yearsLived"></p>Years,
        <br>
        <p id="monthsLived"></p>Months,
        <br>
        <p id="daysLived"></p>Days,
        <br>
        <p id="hoursLived"></p>Hours, and
        <br>
        <p id="minLived"></p>Minutes.
        <br>
        <p id="daysTillBD"></p>Days till your birthday.
    </p>
</div>
```